# Opening an objective c window from a C++ app

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, google-api, oauth-2.0

I have a C++ app that needs to send messages to google API's to do this I need to authenticate.  I have a standalone Objective C authentication utility that is allowing me to do the authentication, but i'm not sure how to integrate it into the C++ app.

How do a trigger an Objective C window to load from C++

Answer (score 1):

You can mix Objective-C and C++ code using Objective-C++. Simply just rename the file that uses both languages with an extension of `.mm`. Any other files that imports any Objective-c++ files will need to be renamed to `.mm` as well.

Comment: How do you invoke the coccoa window from C++?

Comment: You tell me, I have no idea how your code works. Like I said just rename the file extension to `.mm` and you can put objective-c code between c++ code.